# Wild West Domains Integration API

Tags: php

I want to integrate Wild West Domains Reseller APi into my site.. But found no PHP code from anywhere...

Can anybody please Help me..

Thanks in advance.

Uzair

Comment: As in you can't find any details of their API endpoint, or you don't know how to call it from PHP, or you're expecting them to provide a PHP wrapper for the API for you?

Answer (score 3):

Since this is seems to be a commercial product, you might want to [contact them directly](http://www.wildwestdomains.com/resellerplans/support.aspx?ci=44052).

## Customer Support

### Reseller sales/reseller support:

Monday through Friday, 7:30am - 5pm
Saturday, 8:30am - 4pm
Arizona Time
Closed on Sundays
(480) 505-8857

### Domain and product support (24/7):

(480) 624-2500

### Online help:

[Visit the Help Center](http://help.securepaynet.net/?prog_id=wildwestdomains)